# "ls | grep zip" vs. "grep zip $(ls)"

Tags: grep

I'm learning about expansion/ command substitution, and while paying around with an example, noticed that these two commands have different results.

For example, if I cd into `/usr/bin`, and run `ls | grep zip`, grep picks up "zip" in the file names only.

But when I run `grep zip $(ls)` in the same directory, grep also picks up zip in the file content.  Why?  Ubuntu 16.04.

I know it's a newbie question, but it would still be helpful to know why.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not using double quotes on the command line,  just the commands that are shown in double  quotes above.

Comment: That's because grep looks into files. In the second example, you give a list of files to be looked into, while the first one acts like a simple string.

Comment: Please read https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs More sensible approach would be `find -type f -name "*.zip"`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because `grep` can operate in two distinct modes:

> ```
> DESCRIPTION
>    grep searches the named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the
>    given PATTERN.  If no files are specified, or if the file “-” is given,
>    grep  searches  standard  input.   By default, grep prints the matching
>    lines.
> ```

In `ls | grep zip`, the `grep` command sees a list of filenames on its standard input and searches that.

In `grep zip $(ls)`, the shell substitutes the results of the `ls` command as a list words, which `grep` treats as filename arguments, searching each one in turn for the pattern `zip`.

*IMPORTANT NOTE: if any of the filenames contain spaces, then the space-separated parts will be treated as separate arguments, resulting in* `No such file or directory` *errors.* A safer way to search matching files is to use shell globs e.g. `grep 'pattern' *zip*`